# function does not return json data in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, json, orchardcms

I have an existing ASP.Net MVC 5 project, with Fluent NHibernate and Web API. I include it in an Orchard Module in order to work with Orchard CMS, but the problem I got is in my view (Policy_Lookup.cshtml), the function I have does not retrun me the data and I dont know why. in the Google Ghrome Console it shows me this error (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) "http:/localhost:30321/api/VinSearch/getVinResults?VinNum=JT4RN50R9E0009467&Agency=09207")

### Here is my Policy_Lookup.cshtml file:

```
@using Orchard.UI.Resources;

@{
    Script.Require("jquery-1.10.2.js");
}
@using(Script.Head())
{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // URI of the controller
        var URI = "../api/VinSearch";
        @*@Url.Action("Policy_Lookup","Home", new { area = "OIS_New"})*@
        function displayVinResults(VinNum, Agency)
        {
            console.log("hhhh");
            // Send an AJAX request to the controller VinSearch and action getVinResults
            //$.getJSON(URI + '/getVinResults/' + VinNum + '/' + Agency)
            $.getJSON("../api/VinSearch/getVinResults?VinNum=" + VinNum + "&Agency="+Agency)
                .done(function (data) {
                    // code to execute when the data is retrieved from the controller
                    console.log("gbbgb");
                    // check if the data is empty
                    if (data.length == 0) {
                        $("#error").show();
                        $("#btnVinSearch").show();
```

### .........

Here is the route file:
public class Routes : IRouteProvider
    {
        public void GetRoutes(ICollection routes)
        {
            foreach (RouteDescriptor routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
                routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
        }

```
    public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
    {
        return new[] {

            new RouteDescriptor {
                Priority = 5,
                Route = new Route(
                    "OIS_New",
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "OIS_New"},
                        {"controller", "Home"},
                        {"action", "Policy_Lookup"}
                    },
                    new RouteValueDictionary(),
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "OIS_New"}
                    },
                    new MvcRouteHandler())
            }
        };
    }
```

Here is my WebAPI:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
namespace OIS_New
{
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);//to set json response as a default display
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        //to configure the routing convention
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "VinSearch",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{VinNum}/{Agency}",
            defaults: new { VinNum = RouteParameter.Optional, Agency = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.EnsureInitialized();
    }
}
}
```

And this is the action in the controller file:

```
public List<VINResult> getVinResults(String VinNum, String Agency)
{
return dbh.GetVinToVinResult(VinNum, Agency);
}
```

Note: When I run the project, the compiler does not reach this function

Comment: Can you show the route definition and controller action that serve that template?

Comment: Yes of course, I edited the post so you can see the route definition and the controller action.

Comment: Also when I test only the function (http://localhost:30321/api/VinSearch/getVinResults?VinNum=JT4RN50R9E0009467&Agency=09207) in the browser I get an error (HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.). Notice that this project works perfectly without Orchard CMS, I got this error when I integrated it into an Orchard Module.

Comment: Surely you mean the debugger doesn't reach this code. What is the URL you're using? The error message mentions `/api/VinSearch/getVinResults`, and you defined route `OIS_New`. This doesn't look cnsistent.

Comment: Effectively, the debugger doesn't reach the code, I don't know why, I'm a beginner in orchard, surely I miss something, or I made a mistake somewhere. I used this url /api/VinSearch/getVinResults in my projet without Orchard CMS, but when I want to work with Orchard it does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes in Orchard are declared in an implementation of IRouteProvider, even WebAPI routes. Your `Register` method is probably never hit. See http://sebastienros.com/web-api-makes-it-in-orchard for details about the WebAPI implementation in Orchard.

Comment: I tried that before but nothing changes.Thank you very much for your comments :)

Comment: Please update the question with what you tried, exactly.